# MySQL utf8.xml missing in share\charset

Tags: mysql, xml, utf-8, character-encoding, full-text-search

I'm following this tutorial in order to add a collation that will treat "-" (hyphen) as a word character for `fulltext` searches: [Adding a Collation for Full-Text Indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/full-text-adding-collation.html)

However I'm not sure how to carry on from point 2, my table uses `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci` as collation, however utf8.xml file is missing in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets` So is it not possible to add this collation on `UTF8`? or if it is possible then how this xml file should be generated?

Comment: If all your text is limited to English, then it might be easier to switch the charset of the column.

Comment: My text also has Japanese that's why I need utf8

Comment: Suggest posting a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com -- I don't think there are many answerers here that can help you.

Comment: Why not? Is it too advanced?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84341

Comment: Described algorithm applies to _simple collations for 8-bit character sets_. You need to customize a collation based on the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA). [Defining a UCA Collation Using LDML Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ldml-collation-example.html) could help.